# How is arbitrary shift function in digital circuits implemented in digital hardware?

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor

Processors contain an instruction that can shift the input data word by specified number of bits. I assume that this operation would complete in a single clock cycle.

Assuming that the processor deals with 64-bit words and can shift in either direction in a single instruction, it would take 2 set of 64-1 multiplexors where the select signal will be how much we want to shift and the direction.

Are the shift operations implemented using really massive multiplexors? Wouldn't that severely limit the fmax of the design?

Comment: Here's one way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter

Comment: that does still require a lot of sequential logic, this would be hard thing for an FPGA I believe

Comment: Not that complex; this project has one in it: https://opencores.org/projects/aemb

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to assume that the shift happens in one clock cycle, but it is possible to do it in one or at least in a fixed amount of cycles depending on the implementation.

Shifting can be done quickly by implementing a barrel shifter. A textbook barrel shifter that can shift 64 data bits by any 6-bit count between 0 to 63 would only require 64*6 multiplexors. So for each data bit, it would only have a stack of six instances of 2-to-1 muxes.

First there would be 64 multiplexers to either shift by 1 position or not shift at all. The next 64 muxes would shift by 2 or not shift, and so on.

Yes, it may limit the speed, and various techniques exist to improve the textbook implementation.

Comment: Yes, this is how it's done. I wanted to add that in CMOS VLSI a 2:1 multiplexer can be as small as 2 transistors. These multiplexers will not be constructed from a couple of AND gates and an OR gate.